# Override AngularJS + bootstrap.ui rating ng-mouseover behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Rating directive and have it working perfectly for my application except that I would like to disable the ng-mouseover behavior.  For example I want the number of filled stars to remain constant until the user clicks on a star... by default the stars fill/unfill as the user mouses over.

Just thought I'd ask before re-writing this directive for myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. I changed:

```
<rating ng-model="myScore" max="5" XXon-hover="hoveringOver(value)" state-on="\'fa fa-star\'" state-off="\'fa fa-star-o\'" on-leave="" ng-click="updateScore()"></rating>
```

to:

```
<rating ng-model="myScore" max="5" on-hover="" state-on="\'fa fa-star\'" state-off="\'fa fa-star-o\'" on-leave="" ng-click="updateScore()"></rating>
```

I had XX'd out the hover param for testing.  I just changed it to "" and it removed the hover behavior.

For anyone else searching... this also shows how to use Font Awesome Icons with the ui-bootstrap rating directive as well.

Comment: `state-on="\'fa fa-star\'" state-off="\'fa fa-star-o\'"` didn't work me with angular ui-bootstrap 0.13.1